# Exportar archivo que se guarda en libreria

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
File carpetaFmill = new File("C:\\FolderMill");
File arch = new File("C:\\FolderMill\\arch.bat");
if (!arch.exists()) {
    Resource res = new Resource();
    try {
        if (!carpetaFmill.exists()) {
            carpetaFmill.mkdirs();
        }
        res.exportResource(".. Libraries/arch.bat ", carpetaFmill);
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}

System.out.println("cmd /C C:\\FolderMill\\arch.bat " + "-a " + " -r \"" + nombrePuerto + "\" -h " + ip + " -o raw -n 9100 ");



 Process exec = null;
   try {
       exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C C:\\FolderMill\\arch.bat " + "-a " + " -r \"" + nombrePuerto + "\" -h " + ip + " -o raw -n 9100 ");
   } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
   try {
         exec.waitFor();
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Y lo que necesito es que, el archivo.bat me lo coloque en la carpeta de destino, pero no soy capaz. El archivo se encuentra en la carpeta Libraries de mi proyecto.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué clase es Resource? ¿En qué paquete está? Pon la línea de import

Comment: Siento la tardanza pero ya lo solucioné. Muchas Gracias.